# Reduce tabular row height

Tags: tables

I use this code :

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        foo\\
        \vline
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            baz\\
            \vline
            \begin{tabular}{l}
                bar\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}\\
            \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

To be able to do this :

[image]

I need to use a new row to separate hlines, but i want the row to be smaller, how i can do this ?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Right, i edited

Comment: use `\\[some length]` not `\\ \\ `

Comment: If y do that i get this : [link](https://i.imgur.com/mgXyi1D.png), which is not what i want.

Comment: As David suggests, `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        foo\\
        \vline
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            baz\\
            \vline
            \begin{tabular}{l}
                bar\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}\\
            \\[-8pt]
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: Great, thanks you